# java how to split an object to multiple objects inside an array efficiently

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am new to Java so please excuse the way I explain/word this problem I have been given.

Problem: You bought a few bunches of fruit over the weekend. Create a java function that splits a bunch into singular objects inside an array.

```
example input: [{name: "grapes", quantity: 2}]

expected output: [{name: "grapes", quantity: 1}, {name: "grapes", quantity: 1}]
```

ANOTHER EXAMPLE INPUT AND EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
 example input:
 [{name: "currants", quantity: 1},
 {name: "grapes", quantity: 2},
 {name: "bananas", quantity: 2}]

 expected output:
 [{name: "currants", quantity: 1},
 {name: "grapes", quantity: 1},
 {name: "grapes", quantity: 1},
 {name: "bananas", quantity: 1},
 {name: "bananas", quantity: 1}]
```

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because i dont know what you exactly want to do, i wrote quickly a frew lines of Code, like a "proof of concept".

Sure this is maybe not exactly what you want, or what you supposed to to.
But according to the information you give, this could be a soloution for you.

```
public class FruitArry {

public static void main (String [] args){
    ShoppedFruits grapes = new ShoppedFruits("grapes",2);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getFruitsAsArray(grapes)));

}

public static String[] getFruitsAsArray(ShoppedFruits shoppedFruits){
    String[] returnArray = new String[shoppedFruits.quantity];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < shoppedFruits.quantity; i++){
        returnArray[i] = shoppedFruits.toString();
    }
    return returnArray;
}

public static class ShoppedFruits {
    String name;
    int quantity;

    public ShoppedFruits(String name, int quantity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name:"+ name +" quantity: 1";
    }
}
}
```

Cosole output:

```
[name:grapes quantity: 1, name:grapes quantity: 1]
```

Comment: The code you wrote worked for my first example of example input and expected out. I edited my question to include another example which I should have included originally.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the class `Fruit` has the appropriate fields with a full-args constructor and getters:

```java
final List<Fruit> fruits = List.of(
        new Fruit("currants", 1),
        new Fruit("grapes", 2),
        new Fruit("bananas", 2)
);
```

You can yield an infinite stream of the "single item quantities" (`1, 1, 1...`) limited by the actual count of the fruit type `limit(fruit.getQuantity())` and mapping the "single item quantity" as `1` into the new instance using `mapToObj`. The whole structure shall be flatmapped using `flatMap` as you get `Stream<Fruit>` from a single `Fruit`:

```java
final List<Fruit> expanded = fruits.stream()
        .flatMap(fruit -> IntStream.generate(() -> 1)
                .mapToObj(i -> new Fruit(fruit.getName(), i))
                .limit(fruit.getQuantity()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Alternatively limit the stream on creation using `IntStream.range`:

```java
final List<Fruit> expanded = fruits.stream()
        .flatMap(fruit -> IntStream.range(0, fruit.getQuantity())
            .mapToObj(i -> new Fruit(fruit.getName(), 1)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Both of the solutions result in this:

```java
expanded.forEach(System.out::println);
```

> ```
> Fruit[name='currants', quantity=1]
> Fruit[name='grapes', quantity=1]
> Fruit[name='grapes', quantity=1]
> Fruit[name='bananas', quantity=1]
> Fruit[name='bananas', quantity=1]
> ```

Comment: It is returning the address in memory. I'm assuming it's an issue with my getName() method in my Fruit class?

public String getName() {
     return this.name;
}